# Stereo - Depth Range Calculation

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

How to know the depth range of the Stereo camera?

**Camera Specifications**

- Baseline : 6 cm.
- FOV : 120°(D)
- Focal Length: 2.8 mm
- Sensor Size: 1/3 inch
- Resolution: 640 x 480 (from each sensor)

**Calibration procedure:**

- Fisheye module of OpenCV3.1 to calibrate both the camera's
  individually.
- Proceeded by Stereo Calibration.
- Matching Algorithm Used: StereoBM

**Observations:**

- Depth Range - 30 cm to 100 cm.
- The RMS error for the individual camera calibration and stereo
  calibration is less than 0.5.
- The depth value in the range (30 cm - 100 cm) is pretty good, i.e i
  don't get much deviation in the depth.

**Question:**

Is this is the maximum range for the above specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a minimum depth value with

```
minD = tan(fov/2) * baseline/2 = ~5.2cm
```

, but the maximum depth value is infinity. You can verify this by projecting the point at inifinity `(0,0,1,0)` into both of your images (assuming the cameras are centered around the origin and look into +z).

Comment: I can't reproduce your formula. Isn't it tan(fov/2) = baseline/2 / (minD)? I've tried drawing the scheme and it should be a right triangle where baseline/2 is to the opposite of the fov/2 angle